# ;How to create running total that resets upon a NULL value T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to create a running total column that resets each time it encounters a null or multiple null values. I expect to maintain the ID partition and date order.
I expect the result as the table below

| ID | date | value | Running_T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SA223 | 10/07/2018 | 3 | 3 |
| SA223 | 11/07/2018 | 6 | 9 |
| SA223 | 25/07/2018 | NULL | NULL |
| SA223 | 16/08/2018 | 11 | 11 |
| SA223 | 17/08/2018 | 9 | 20 |
| SA555 | 15/05/2019 | 4 | 4 |
| SA555 | 27/05/2019 | 13 | 17 |
| SA555 | 11/07/2019 | NULL | NULL |
| SA555 | 21/11/2019 | NULL | NULL |
| SA555 | 20/02/2020 | 4 | 4 |
| SA555 | 27/05/2020 | 1 | 5 |
| SA555 | 23/07/2020 | 2 | 7 |

I tried the code below but it messed up the ordering and does not deal with Null values as I want.

```
SELECT ID
       , date
       , value
       ,Running_T = SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, (CASE WHEN [value] IS NOT NULL THEN [value] ELSE NULL END) ORDER BY [date])
FROM dim.event_data
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is a classic Gaps And Islands problem.** There are more efficient solutions but a simple one is as follows:

You can use a conditional running `COUNT` to number each set of rows. Then do a running `SUM` over that group number to get the final result

```sql
WITH Counted AS (
    SELECT *,
      GrpId = COUNT(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM event_data ed
)
SELECT *,
    Running = SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GrpId ORDER BY Date)
FROM Counted;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/h24QqWES)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
SELECT ID,
    date,
    value,
    CASE
        WHEN value IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) 
    END AS Running_T
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**